# UWP TreeView data binding and reflecting changes

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop, treeview, viewmodel, observablecollection

Does UWP TreeView reflect changes in items by dragging and droppping into it's associated ItemsSource from VM? For example, I associate TreeView with VM ObservableCollection list. When I add some items by executing command from VM that populate that collection with new items, they do show up in TreeView UI. However, if I drag and drop item inside TreeView, underlaying list does not change? What am I doing wrong? Should TreeView update and observable collection based on my actions?

Here is my VM:

```
public class MySampleViewModel : MyBase 
{
    public ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> storageFolders { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; }

    public ICommand ChangeCommand { get; }

    public MySampleViewModel()
    {
        AddFilesFolders();
    }

    private void AddFilesFolders()
    {
        FolderInfo ff1 = new FolderInfo();
        ff1.FolderName = "Folder " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ff1.IsFolder = true;
        ff1.subFolders = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

        storageFolders.Add(ff1);

        FolderInfo ffkeko = new FolderInfo();
        ffkeko.FolderName = "subitem" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ffkeko.subFolders = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

        ff1.subFolders.Add(ffkeko);

        FolderInfo ff = new FolderInfo();
        ff.FolderName = "servername " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ff.subFolders = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

        storageFolders.Add(ff);
    }
}

public class MyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class FolderInfo : MyBase
{
    private string _FolderName;
    public string FolderName
    {
        get { return _FolderName; }
        set
        {
            if (_FolderName != value)
            {
                _FolderName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FolderName");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsFolder;
    public bool IsFolder
    {
        get { return _IsFolder; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsFolder != value)
            {
                _IsFolder = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsFolder");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> subFolders { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FolderName;
    }
}
```

And here is my XAML for TreeView:

```
<localdata:MyTreeView 
x:Name="treeview" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding storageFolders,Mode=OneWay}" 
Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle1}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are actually assigning a new `ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>` instance to the `subFolders` property when there is a change, but data binding is bound to the previous instance, so it does not observe this change. There are two solutions to this problem:

1) Change the instance and raise `PropertyChanged` event:

```
private ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> _subFolders = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();
public ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> subFolders
{
   get => _subFolders;
   set
   {
      _subFolders = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

2) Instead of assigning a new instance, clear the original one and just add new items:

So instead of:

```
ff.subFolders = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();
ff.subFolders.Add(something);
```

You will do:

```
ff.subFolders.Clear();
ff.subFolders.Add(something);
```

Comment: Do you have some source code to confirm it? Had added changes to my VM as you suggested but still no change, VM is not updated after moving items in Tree...

Comment: I don't unfortunately, but if you create a sample repo on GitHub, I can check what the problem is

Comment: I will check it out tomorrow